# How can I use call sound not media sound with agora on the android web browser?

Tags: android, web, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

On Android Web Browser (Chrome or other browsers as well), the sound comes out to media sound, not the call sound. (in Demo too)

So, when the user controls the volume up/down buttons, it controls the call sound not the media sound. So, this misleads the users behaviours and it cause a lot of uncomfortable situations. And it's a bit difficult to control it on old android devices. Is there any way to solve this problem?

I tried with appRTC demo(https://appr.tc/). And the sound comes out to the call sound. And I can control the volume with the volume up/down buttons.

Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API method to play audio as a call volume on the Agora Web SDK as of now. Media volume is the intended way of playing media on the browser. If you want to use the call volume you can check out the Android SDK instead.

Comment: Well, if you use AppRTC on web browser, it works as I intended. So, WebRTC can use in-call volume on the browser.